# How do I surface my query as a view in my already established Power BI dashboard?

Tags: sql-server, powerbi

I have a query that returns a specific dataset from a table using loops and declared variables. I'd like to turn this dataset into a view in SQL server so I can use it with an already established Power BI dashboard connected to the SQL server. However, I've learned recently that declared variables cannot exist in a view. I'd like to use the original table as well as the new queried/filtered table in Power BI while keeping the relationships. Here's a sample of the code I'm using:

```
DECLARE @ctr INT 
SET @ctr = 0

SELECT *
FROM [Database_UAT].[dbo].[CUSTODIAN_TAXLOT]
WHERE [TaxLotDate] = (SELECT [TaxLotDate]
                        FROM [Database_UAT].[dbo].[CUSTODIAN_TAXLOT]
                        GROUP BY [TaxLotDate]
                        ORDER BY [TaxLotDate] DESC
                        OFFSET @ctr ROWS
                        FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY)
```

And here is the basic logic of the loop:

```
WHILE @ctr <= 10
BEGIN
    SET @ctr = @ctr + 1;
    IF @ctr >= 10
        BEGIN
            print 'Good'
            BREAK;
        END
    print @ctr
END
```

I'm fairly new to using these tools in a professional capacity, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: This is my first post here not sure if I'm doing this right, but to provide more context I've included the entire code in question. The loop is taking the total of the `[TotalCostBase]` column grouped by the most recent date in the `[TaxLotDate]` column and is comparing it to the average of the last 6 dates worth of totals.

```
DECLARE @ctr INT
SET @ctr = 0

IF (SELECT ft.[TotalCostBase]
       FROM (
              SELECT [TaxLotDate], sum([TotalCostBase]) AS "TotalCostBase"
              FROM [Database_UAT].[dbo].[CUSTODIAN_TAXLOT]
              GROUP BY [TaxLotDate]
              ORDER BY [TaxLotDate] DESC
              OFFSET @ctr ROWS
              FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
                ) ft) <= (SELECT avg(dt.[TotalCostBase]) * 0.75
                         FROM (
                                SELECT [TaxLotDate], sum([TotalCostBase]) AS "TotalCostBase"
                                FROM [Database_UAT].[dbo].[CUSTODIAN_TAXLOT]
                                GROUP BY TaxLotDate
                                ORDER BY TaxLotDate DESC
                                OFFSET 1 ROWS
                                FETCH NEXT 6 ROWS ONLY
                                ) dt)
BEGIN
    WHILE (SELECT ft.[TotalCostBase]
         FROM (
                 SELECT [TaxLotDate], sum([TotalCostBase]) AS "TotalCostBase"
                 FROM [Database_UAT].[dbo].[CUSTODIAN_TAXLOT]
                 GROUP BY [TaxLotDate]
                 ORDER BY [TaxLotDate] DESC
                 OFFSET @ctr ROWS
                 FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
                    ) ft) <= (SELECT avg(dt.[TotalCostBase]) * 0.75
                             FROM (
                                    SELECT [TaxLotDate], sum([TotalCostBase]) AS "TotalCostBase"
                                    FROM [Database_UAT].[dbo].[CUSTODIAN_TAXLOT]
                                    GROUP BY TaxLotDate
                                    ORDER BY TaxLotDate DESC
                                    OFFSET 1 ROWS
                                    FETCH NEXT 6 ROWS ONLY 
                                    ) dt)
    BEGIN
        SET @ctr = @ctr + 1
        IF (SELECT ft.[TotalCostBase]
          FROM (
                  SELECT [TaxLotDate], sum([TotalCostBase]) AS "TotalCostBase"
                  FROM [Database_UAT].[dbo].[CUSTODIAN_TAXLOT]
                  GROUP BY [TaxLotDate]
                  ORDER BY [TaxLotDate] DESC
                  OFFSET @ctr ROWS
                  FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
                    ) ft) > (SELECT avg(dt.[TotalCostBase]) * 0.75
                             FROM (
                                    SELECT [TaxLotDate], sum([TotalCostBase]) AS "TotalCostBase"
                                    FROM [Database_UAT].[dbo].[CUSTODIAN_TAXLOT]
                                    GROUP BY TaxLotDate
                                    ORDER BY TaxLotDate DESC
                                    OFFSET 1 ROWS 
                                    FETCH NEXT 6 ROWS ONLY 
                                    ) dt)
            BEGIN
                SELECT *
                FROM [Database_UAT].[dbo].[CUSTODIAN_TAXLOT]
                WHERE [TaxLotDate] = (SELECT [TaxLotDate]
                                        FROM [Database_UAT].[dbo].[CUSTODIAN_TAXLOT]
                                        GROUP BY [TaxLotDate]
                                        ORDER BY [TaxLotDate] DESC
                                        OFFSET @ctr ROWS
                                        FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY)
            BREAK
            END
    END
END

ELSE

BEGIN
    SELECT *
            FROM [Database_UAT].[dbo].[CUSTODIAN_TAXLOT]
            WHERE [TaxLotDate] = (SELECT [TaxLotDate]
                                    FROM [Database_UAT].[dbo].[CUSTODIAN_TAXLOT]
                                    GROUP BY [TaxLotDate]
                                    ORDER BY [TaxLotDate] DESC
                                    OFFSET @ctr ROWS
                                    FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change the logic to return a single resultset to use it in Power BI.  You can also encapsulate the logic in a multi-statement Table-Valued Function or Stored Procedure.

Comment: My apologies, I should have given more context. The loop is taking the total of a column grouped by the most recent date in the table and is comparing it to the average of the last 6 days worth of totals. Please see my edit above.

Comment: See updated answer.